# tensorflow restore only variables

Tags: tensorflow

I do some training in Tensorflow and save the whole session using a saver:

```
# ... define model

# add a saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# ... run a session
    # ....
    # save the model
    save_path = saver.save(sess,fileSaver)
```

It works fine, and I can successfully restore the whole session by using the exact same model and calling:

```
saver.restore(sess, importSaverPath)
```

Now I want to modify only the optimizer while keeping the rest of the model constant (the computation graph stays the same apart from the optimizer):

```
# optimizer used before
# optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer
#    (learning_rate = learningRate).minimize(costPrediction)
# the new optimizer I want to use
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer
    (learning_rate = learningRate, decay = 0.9, momentum = 0.1,
    epsilon = 1e-5).minimize(costPrediction)
```

I also want to continue the training from the last graph state I saved (i.e., I want to restore the state of my variables and continue with another training algorithm). Of course I cannot use:

```
saver.restore
```

any longer, because the graph has changed.

So my question is: is there a way to restore only variables using the saver.restore command (or even, maybe for later use, only a subset of variables), when the whole session has been saved? I looked for such feature in the API documentation and online, but could not find any example / detailed enough explanations that could help me get it to work.

Comment: Consider including both optimizers in your graph.  you can then elect to call either in a session.  Switching optimizers does not require saving/restoring so I thought I would mention this to make sure you are aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to restore a subset of variables by passing the list of variables as the `var_list` argument to the [`Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) constructor. However, when you change the optimizer, additional variables may have been created (momentum accumulators, for instance) and variable associated with the previous optimizer, if any, would have been removed from the model. So simply using the old `Saver` object to restore will not work, especially if you had constructed it with the default constructor, which uses [`tf.all_variables`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L775) as the argument to `var_list` parameter. You have to construct the `Saver` object on the subset of variables that you created in your model and then `restore` would work. Note that, this would leave the new variables created by the new optimizer uninitialized, so you have to explicitly initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem. Inspired by keveman' s answer. My solution is:

1. Define your new graph, (here only new optimizer related variables are different from the old graph).
2. Get all variables using tf.global_variables(). This return a var list I called g_vars.
3. Get all optimizer related variables using tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_by_suffix('some variable filter'). The filter may be RMSProp or RMSPRrop_*. This function returns a var list I called exclude_vars.
4. Get the variables in g_vars but not in exclude_vars. Simply use

   vars = [item for item in g_vars if item not in exclude_vars]

these vars are common vars in both new and old graph, which you can restore from old model now.

Comment: init_ckpt = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(check_point, vars)         
init_ckpt(sess)

Answer (score 0):

you could recover the original `Saver` from a `MetaGraph` protobuf first and then use that saver to restore **all** old variables safely. For a concrete example, you can take a look at the `eval.py` script: [TensorFlow: How do I release a model without source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462229/tensorflow-how-do-i-release-a-model-without-source-code/38921538#38921538)