# TensorFlow: How do I release a model without source code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow + Python.

I am curious if I can release a saved Tensorflow model (architecture + trained variables) without detailed source code. I'm aware of `tf.train.Saver()`, but it looks to save only variables, and in order to restore/run them, a user needs to "define" the same architecture.

For the testing/running purpose only, is there a way to release a saved {architecture+trained variables} without source code, so that a user can just cast a query and get a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) project is intended to make this use case straightforward (assuming that the end user is only using the model for inference, not training). TensorFlow Serving includes an `Exporter` class that takes your `tf.train.Saver`, the `tf.GraphDef` that defines your overall model, and a "signature" that describes the inputs to and output from your model.

The [basics tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) has a good introduction to exporting your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `Saver` from the MetaGraphDef (saved with checkpoints by default: those .meta files). and then use that Saver to restore your model. So users don't have to re-define your graph in their code. But then they still need to figure out the model signature (input, output variables). I solve this using `tf.Collection` (but i am interested to find better ways to do it as well).

You can take a look at my example implementation (the `eval.py` evaluate a model without re-defining a model):

- reconstruct saver from meta graph https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/eval.py#L18
- get input variables from collections https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/eval.py#L58
- how to define your model https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/models/cp2f3d.py

Comment: With your implementation, do you retrieve the correct weights from the trained model? I can only see that you get the input and output layers (https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/eval.py#L43 + https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/eval.py#L45)

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup yes, the saver takes care of loading the binary out of the checkpoint file for each variable. The lines you referred to retrieve the necessary input and output variables (rather than layers), so we can execute the graph in evaluation: think of them as the function signature, a visual classifier maps image -> class logits. To put it in another way, without these variables (placeholders are variables too), we cannot construct this call: https://github.com/falcondai/cifar10/blob/master/eval.py#L67