# Tensorflow: How do I export a model to be used by a different module?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I've trained my model and saved it, and now I want to call it from another Python module. I now want to evaluate a few items, but I want the evaluation function to be called from outside.
Is there an accepted way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "called from outside"? If you can provide some sample code, it will help

Comment: For example, I have a model that classifies images. I now want to classify an image, image_1, from a different file, called get_images.py. How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried to `restore()` the model in the second file? Though I'm suspecting you are facing this issue as your code isn't modular

Comment: Don't I have to define the graph in order to use restore? Ideally I don't wan to to have to define the graph in the second file

Comment: I think this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462229/tensorflow-how-do-i-release-a-model-without-source-code

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!